# Why do I need to change the bounds of integration?

Tags: calculus

Why do I need to change the bounds of integration? What is the procedure, and why?

**problem (15):**
[image]

Comment: $u=\sin(0)=0$ and $u=\sin(\pi /2)=1$, then $3\int_0^1 u^2\;du$

Comment: OK but what is an indicator that I need to change the bounds of integration

Comment: What is the idea of substitution? It is the chain rule in reverse. This means if you want to find an antiderivative of of $f(u(x)) u'(x) = (G(u(x)))'$, where $G$ is an antiderivative of $f$. We have $$\int_a^b f(u(x)) u'(x) = \int_a^b (G(u(x)))' dx = G(u(x)) \vert_a^b = G(u) \vert_{u(a)}^{u(b)} = \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} f(u) du.$$ So everytime we make a substitution, we need to change the boundaries too. Namely, we need to replace $a$ by $u(a)$ and $b$ by $u(b)$.

Answer (score 2):

The bounds of the integral are values of $x$ because it is an integral with respect to $x$. If you make the substitution and integrate with respect to $u$ then the bounds need to be values of $u$, so $0$ must change to $u(0)=\sin0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ must change to $u(\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle I=\int_a^b f(g(t))g'(t)\text{d}t$. If we substitute $x=g(t)$, then

$\displaystyle I= \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\text{d}x$.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you aren't actually changing the bounds of integration.  Start by thinking of a more expanded notation for the integral.  Rather than just giving numbers on the bounds, we should imagine that we are setting values for variables:

$$ \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} 3\,\sin^2(x)\,\cos(x)\,dx $$

Now, it becomes a little more obvious.  Let's do the substitution and leave the bounds of integration alone:

$$ \int_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} 3 u^2\,du $$

This readily integrates as

$$ u^3 \biggr|_{x = 0}^{x = \frac{\pi}{2}} $$

So, this is a true statement, but it is unhelpful!  I have a function and I need to evaluate it at $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ but the formula is in terms of $u$ not $x$!

That's why we have to transform it.  We need a value to plug in for $u$ but we only have a value for $x$.  However, thankfully, we have a formula which transforms our $x$ into $u$: $u = \sin(x)$.  So, we can now write our evaluation as:

$$ u^3 \biggr|_{u = \sin(0)}^{u = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} = u^3 \biggr|_{u = 0}^{u = 1} = (1)^3 - (0)^3 = 1$$

So the reason for the transformation is that we did the integral in terms of $u$ but the bounds were in terms of $x$.  Equivalently, we could have just taken the final formula and made it in terms of $x$.  So, instead of $u^3$ we would have $\sin^3(x)$.  Then we can keep our bounds in terms of $x$ and evaluate it directly at $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.